# What is a good editor for linked data?

Tags: linked-data, programming

I  mainly serialize linked data through the Java Jena library. One of the features I really like is where you create a java class from an OWL file, which in eclipse enable [autocomplete](http://andrawaag.wordpress.com/2012/03/23/how-to-generate-java-files-from-owl-files-in/), when coding an open data serializer.

I would love to have the same autocomplete functionality in a simple editor. I often write triples in my preferred text editor [Textmate](http://macromates.com/), where I just type of copy/paste the long URIs. Having an editor that would autocomplete some preset prefixes would be really convenient.

Does it exist?

Answer (score 5):

My currently favoured text editor [jEdit](http://jedit.org/) has a simple yet effective word completion feature (Menu Edit > Complete word; default shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>). It takes its word list from the opened document and includes keywords of the file's programming language (in case it is code). Word-delimiting characters can be user-defined as described on the page [Working with Words](http://www.jedit.org/users-guide/words.html) (section *What's a Word?*) in the comprehensive [jEdit User's Guide](http://www.jedit.org/users-guide/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

I use [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/), and a number of plugins using [package control](https://sublime.wbond.net/). Most usefully this Turtle plugin that autocompletes things based on what you've already typed:

https://github.com/abcoates/sublime-text-turtle-sparql

This is assuming you're writing in Turtle, and therefore using prefixes. If I'm working in other RDF formats, I use [Jena rdfcat](https://sublime.wbond.net/) to transform files into Turtle and back out again - makes it far easier for editing most of the time.

Honourable mention to Phil Lord's [Tawny-OWL](https://github.com/phillord/tawny-owl), which might not be appropriate for what you want particularly, but does have some really cool RDF-conscious autocompletes built in (from what I remember!) and allows you to create models programmatically. Not used it in anger yet...

Answer (score 2):

There is a new and really cool Linked Data Editor - the Fluent Semantic Editor 2014 from Cognitum.

For a first impression you can watch their video at http://www.youtube.com/embed/2KEC4q_xmWY?hd=1&feature=youtu.be&autoplay=1

Product Homepage is: http://www.cognitum.eu/Semantics/FluentEditor/